# Connect two separate projects under single domain

Tags: iis, project-management, projects-and-solutions

[image]I have an A project developed using MVC, SQL and a B project developed using weboforms, SQL. I have single domain name to publish. So I planned to put single page with two links and from that page access two separate projects. How can I do this? Can I add a common page in project B and set that as start up project? It will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Virtual directory no need to put single page with two links and from that page access two separate projects.

Please refer [how to create Virtual directory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172138)

Comment: I have created virtual directory under project A and the url like : www.A.com/B - but its not working. I am working on IIS 6.0

Comment: I have added the screenshot of error after creating virtual directory

Comment: There are many reasons why you are getting Error 500 Please refer https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/942031

After success it will look like 
www.domain.com/A And www.domain.com/B

Comment: I have physical path /inetpub/wwwroot/A and inside A folder I added B - publish files. In IIS created the site for A using domain.com and for B check with domain.com/B.. Is this the correct process? or need to change ?

Comment: Step 1: inetpub/wwwroot/A and inetpub/wwwroot/B. Step 2: add site separately

Comment: Step 2: I have completed but i need to use same domain name for these seperate sites